# Installing this plugin

Tags: firefox, plugins, makefile, installation

I want to install [this plugin](https://github.com/partounian/twitter-feed-eradicator) in my firefox browser.

I tried the obvious thing of downloading and running `make install BROWSER=firefox webpack`.

However the terminal greets me with a `error 127`.

Whole terminal feed:

```
npm install -g webpack
make: npm: No se encontró el programa
Makefile:24: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'install'
make: *** [install] Error 127
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/twitter-feed-eradicator$ make install BROWSER=firefox
npm install -g webpack
make: npm: No se encontró el programa
Makefile:24: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'install'
make: *** [install] Error 127
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/twitter-feed-eradicator$ make install BROWSER='firefox'
npm install -g webpack
make: npm: No se encontró el programa
Makefile:24: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'install'
make: *** [install] Error 127
jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/twitter-feed-eradicator$ make install BROWSER='firefox' webpack
npm install -g webpack
make: npm: No se encontró el programa
Makefile:24: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'install'
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

Specs: Ubuntu 16, Firefox 48

What can I do?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the npm package installed on your system.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you!